# Linq Expression Confusion combined with defered execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, reflection, routes

I want to execute a specific part of code once a path matches a specific need or pattern. I will import a few paths from different plugins, which will be searched through and sorted out which are useful or not for my intention.

The idea is that once i get a match from those pathes, i want to create an instance of this class and call it´s method to return a `view`.

I can figure out enough to be able to pass in a delegate and call the appropriate code but that still leaves me holding a pointer to the class, which i dont want. I want create an instance of this class and to call the desired method.

Here is an outline:

```
public class TestView : IView
{
    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) {}
}

class TestViewCreator
{
    public IView CreateView(object Arguments)
    {
        return new TestView();
    }
}

public class CentralStash
{
    // T = TestViewCreator
    // How do I describe the method I want to call (CreateView)?
    public void RegisterPath<T>(string url, object Arguements)
    {

    }

    public IView GetView(string url)
    {
        var viewCreator = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
        //How do I call the method description on the type that I have jsut instanced?
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've got the feeling that I should probably be using routes here, or possibly an expression? I know this is possible to do with delegates but I don't want a few objects laying round because of their pointers.

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Of couse i could just create the interface:

```
public interface IViewCreator
{
    public IView CreateView(object Arguments);
}
```

And create one of them to call `CreateView`, but I was hoping to make this more powerful.

Comment: Passing in a delegate is much, much better. No need for the object arguments param. And a delegate overhead? So what, if you have them pass in strings and type parameters and save those, you still have objects.

Comment: this dosn't make much sense ... if you edit it so it does i can probably answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IView GetView(string url)
{
    object viewCreatorObj = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    TestViewCreator viewCreator=? viewCreatorObj as TestViewCreator;

    return viewCreator.CreateView(null);
}
```